# Why doesn't my latch work (schematic attached)?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, latch

I tried to make a simple latch with a PNP transistor and a MOSFET.  The idea is that initially it is off, when you press the button it turns on and stays on.

But it doesn't stay on.

Here is the circuit:
[image]

I've tried it with both 12v and 5v, it doesn't work.

I also tried increasing the pullup and pulldown resistors R1 and R4 to 4.7K, in which case the LED is initially on.  (Not sure why!)

I attached a picture of the actual implementation, I don't know how much you can make out from it but here it is:
[image]

Comment: The schematic looks OK, so maybe you have a wiring error. Can you show us your actual implementation?

Comment: the switch resistance can be the problem. It should be tied to base not drain using same as R2

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I connected it to the base, still the same problem.  I attached a picture of the breadboard..

Comment: What's the PN of your MOSFET?

Comment: @ThePhoton It's an IRFZ34N, data sheet is here: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz34n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b133f2200

Comment: the two Rs going to FET and is or are almost shorting G-D. be neater and keep switch to Base with 2.2k

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75  OK switch connects base to ground with 2.2k, now nothing happens when I press the switch.

Comment: that proves you have a fault. get a DMM and check V on collector, base and pin labels

Comment: What kind of fault should I be looking for?  I swapped out both transistors, still the same happens.

Comment: With button up, Emitter Base Collector voltages are 5.2, 5.2, 0.  With button down, it is 5.2, 4.5, 1.0

Comment: wiring fault.. test PNP as a switch ONLY and FET as a switch ONLY . If you dont have a DMM use LED + 1K as a probe with wire.

Comment: EBC is backwards ? 1.0 must be near 5V with no load. check orientation , disconnect collector load

Comment: Okay the voltages work correctly with no load on collector. It all  seems to work correctly if I increase the R4 resistance from 1K to 4.7K.  Except that sometimes the MOSFET remembers its state so the circuit starts with transistors on when you disconnect and reconnect power..

Comment: What is the value of the resistor in series with the button?

Comment: @immibis That one is 2.2K

Comment: What about the LED resistor value and LED voltage drop? I'm trying to calculate if 2.2k might be too much resistance to pull down the BJT's base, given that it has a resistor in series with it and an LED+resistor in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a cap to ground at/near your mosfet gate. Perhaps across \$R_4\$ in your circuit.

Try this as an option:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYqTvO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_3\$ limits sudden currents to \$C_1\$ and the gate of \$M_1\$ and oscillations, but still also allows \$C_1\$ to discharge pretty fast through the LED load when the power is removed. \$R_4\$ is needed to keep trace currents from charging the mosfet gate and to also further discharge \$C_1\$ when the LED isn't conducting much anymore.

The above circuit is set up for an LED current of about \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ as an example. If you plan some monster LED later on, the values and part selections would need to be changed.

---

EDIT:

I'd much have preferred the use of another BJT rather than a mosfet. In that case, the following circuit is an easy derivative, robust, and doesn't need \$C_1\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flmCPx.png)</sup>

You could also get rid of one (or perhaps even both) of the two \$33\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ resistors and further simplify it. The LED load is plenty, already, so I don't see much real need for \$R_4\$. And given that, the whole thing should power up in the right state also without the need for \$R_2\$. But this applies so long as there is a load. Otherwise, I'd keep at least one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  What is the purpose of adding a capacitor?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Well, I'd have much preferred using a BJT rather than a mosfet. But with the mosfet in your arrangement I'm mostly bothered by \$C_{GD}\$.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Let me know if it works for you. I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Hi!  yes, it worked, thank you!  I believe the problem with my original design was that the pullup and pulldown resistors were too small!

Comment: (By the way the reason I used a MOSFET is because I need it to drive a motor!)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman You can drive a motor with a BJT, too. Cheaper and less parts, besides. (And I think probably more predictable. But that's just me.)